# Can you power a 3.3 led with an arduino 5v output?

Tags: arduino, led, voltage-divider, 5v, 3.3v

I have a led that can handle 10 milliamps at 3.3v. Can I use a voltage divider and a plus resistor to power it from an arduino nano 5v digital pin? 
Maybe something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSPcI3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Arduino output pin current is 40mA max. So yes it is possible and you only need one resistor as pointed out by Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5 volts needs to reduce to 3.3 volts at 10 mA. That's a resistance of 1.7 volts / 10 mA = 170 ohms. So, to be on the safe side, feed your LED via one resistor of 180 ohms directly from 5 volts.

[image]

Comment: It's a 5110 lcd backlight that is currently powered with the 3.3v output and a 320 Ohm resistor. That's where I got the 10 milliams from. Will it still work in this case?
https://lastminuteengineers.com/nokia-5110-lcd-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: @Reider - the spec you left doesn't help. If powered from 3.3 volts and the LED drops 2 volts then the LED current through a 320 ohm resistor is 1.2 volts / 320 = 3.75 mA. You have to get this right to be able to work out what resistor you need to power it from 5 volts. Without that knowledge it's guesswork.

Comment: Yeah you are right so I measured. The voltage in is 3.62v after the resistor it is 2.88 so the led should be dropping 0.74v. Then 5v - 0.74v that is 4.26v with 8.73 milliamps that should be a 484 ohm resistor. Am I right? Also if the led is rated to 3.3V don't know if that could be a problem.

Comment: (3.62 - 2.88)/320 = 2.313 mA. Dropping 5 volts to 2.88 volts at 2.313 mA is (5 - 2.88)/ 2.313 mA  = 917 ohm and not 484 ohms. Don't try and short cut the math - work out the current then reapply that current to the 5 volt scenario.

Comment: Thanks, working now with a 1K resistor.

Comment: Funny schematic but OK. ;) You can go with resistors higher values. 1K for example. With SMD leds, you can go as high as 10K, and 22K for green SMD leds. Melon Hat leds needs more current to be visible.